# Any way to download from Scribd?

Tags: scribd

Is there any way I can download from Scribd? I need to download a few documents for my research.

Answer (score 1):

Press the big "Download" button and follow the instructions? For each file you download you have to upload one document. Otherwise you could pay for a subscription.